# How to add Class to ul li

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass

hey i have this javascript code

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://api.import.io/store/connector/b5caf0ef-1e6b-4fba-9fa4-21e475196673/_query?input=webpage/url:http%3A%2F%2Fnuzzel.com%2FWAStatzz%3Fsort%3Dfriends%26when%3D2&&_apikey=e4fb993c758a43dda0ca9135d3b3264deebed4b302b0d342e2b3fabb2b49afc9c14493d0d53d65d0ea2a0fd19b45f6d10cda5252f76410921188d38cb4e6db8fc28527d64207329b2c86bdc5119bac97'
}).done(function(data) {
  console.log(data);

  var html = "";
  $.each(data.results, function(index, item) {
    html += "<ul>";
    html += "<li><a href='" + item['headline'] + "'>" + item['headline/_text'] + "</a></li>";
    html += "<li>" + item.description + "</li>";
    html += "</ul>";
  });
  
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".container").append(html);
  }, 1500);
});
```

and i need a class (.list-group) added to the output ul list 
and to the li element (.list-group-item)

i tried it with

```
 $("ul").addClass("list-group");
 $("li").addClass("list-group-item");
```

but its not working

Comment: Why not adding in the HTML, that you already compose? `html += "<ul class='list-group'>";`

Comment: Whay don't you want to do this while concatenating strings?

Comment: did you tried your `addClass` code inside `setTimeout()` method call?

Comment: right after appending it to the container.. but your addClass code will add classes on entire document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest way is to add right where you are generating HTML string. Like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://api.import.io/store/connector/b5caf0ef-1e6b-4fba-9fa4-21e475196673/_query?input=webpage/url:http%3A%2F%2Fnuzzel.com%2FWAStatzz%3Fsort%3Dfriends%26when%3D2&&_apikey=e4fb993c758a43dda0ca9135d3b3264deebed4b302b0d342e2b3fabb2b49afc9c14493d0d53d65d0ea2a0fd19b45f6d10cda5252f76410921188d38cb4e6db8fc28527d64207329b2c86bdc5119bac97'
}).done(function(data) {
  console.log(data);

  var html = "";
  $.each(data.results, function(index, item) {
    html += "<ul class='list-group'>";
    html += "<li class='list-group-item'><a href='" + item['headline'] + "'>" + item['headline/_text'] + "</a></li>";
    html += "<li class='list-group-item'>" + item.description + "</li>";
    html += "</ul>";
  });

  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".container").append(html);
  }, 1500);
});
```

Alternatively, you can do it just after appending to DOM, like this:

```
$(".container").append(html);
$(".container > ul").addClass('list-group');
$(".container > ul > li").addClass('list-group-item');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://api.import.io/store/connector/b5caf0ef-1e6b-4fba-9fa4-21e475196673/_query?input=webpage/url:http%3A%2F%2Fnuzzel.com%2FWAStatzz%3Fsort%3Dfriends%26when%3D2&&_apikey=e4fb993c758a43dda0ca9135d3b3264deebed4b302b0d342e2b3fabb2b49afc9c14493d0d53d65d0ea2a0fd19b45f6d10cda5252f76410921188d38cb4e6db8fc28527d64207329b2c86bdc5119bac97'
}).done(function(data) {
  console.log(data);

  var html = "";
  $.each(data.results, function(index, item) {
    html += '<ul class="list-group">';
    html += '<li class="list-group-item"><a href="' + item['headline'] + '">' + item['headline/_text'] + "</a></li>";
    html += '<li class="list-group-item">' + item.description + "</li>";
    html += "</ul>";
  });



  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".container").append(html);
  }, 1500);
});
```

Comment: @answerer: don't you see the syntax errors in your markup?

Comment: You have syntax error, you can't have double quote inside double quotes like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it immediately after appending it to the container

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://api.import.io/store/connector/b5caf0ef-1e6b-4fba-9fa4-21e475196673/_query?input=webpage/url:http%3A%2F%2Fnuzzel.com%2FWAStatzz%3Fsort%3Dfriends%26when%3D2&&_apikey=e4fb993c758a43dda0ca9135d3b3264deebed4b302b0d342e2b3fabb2b49afc9c14493d0d53d65d0ea2a0fd19b45f6d10cda5252f76410921188d38cb4e6db8fc28527d64207329b2c86bdc5119bac97'
}).done(function(data) {
  console.log(data);

  var html = "";
  $.each(data.results, function(index, item) {
    html += "<ul>";
    html += "<li><a href='" + item['headline'] + "'>" + item['headline/_text'] + "</a></li>";
    html += "<li>" + item.description + "</li>";
    html += "</ul>";
  });
  $(".container").append(html);
  $("ul").addClass("list-group");
  $("li").addClass("list-group-item");
});
```

I don't think a `setTimeout` is required here.

Or if you prefer your setTimeout for some reason then keep `addClass` inside `setTimeout`

```
  setTimeout(function() {
      $(".container").append(html);
      $("ul").addClass("list-group"); //or $(".container ul")
      $("li").addClass("list-group-item");// or $(".container ul li")
  }, 1500);
```

But in both scenarios, it addClass needs to be done after `ul` and `li` has become part of your DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Save the targetContainer in a variable, then use the `find`method to get the li and ul like this:

```
targetContainer = $(".container");

setTimeout(function() {
        targetContainer.append(html);

        targetContainer.find('ul').addClass('list-group');
        targetContainer.find('ul li').addClass('list-group-item');
      }, 1500);
```

Working codepen: http://codepen.io/gpincheiraa/pen/YqQjwe?editors=0010

Answer (score 0):

I bet your problem is related with that timeout you have. Probably you try to get DOM elements that have not been initialized yet.
I suggest your code in the setTimeout function:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $(".container").append(html);
    $("ul").addClass("list-group");
    $("li").addClass("list-group-item");
}, 1500);
```

This way you will have already initialized DOM, and the $("ul") and $("li") will find elements to add classes to.